# Deploy java program on Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

A web application has been developed in C# which hits my Java code through a restful web service which returns a JSON response.This process was working on a local machine with tomcat server. Now my Java application needs to be hosted on an external server in Linux environment.

Using putty, I logged into the particular hostname and as a root admin.
I have installed Java JDK 1.7, Apache tomcat server 7, my Java application as a war file is placed in the webapps folder. I can start the tomcat server too.

My question is:

1. How do I hit my application from windows. Is it `http://x.y.z.k:8080//MYAPPNAME(war file name)/`?
2. How do i check the java logs in the linux env?
3. Also I have a set of files that I read from my windows folders as in `C://uploads//file.txt or C:\DeveloperTool\Pluggins\`

I replaced them with the linux structure in my java code. as `/home/opt/file.txt` 
Will this work?

Comment: 'Will this work?' Did you try it?

Comment: Also the url in my ajax call is url: 'http://localhost:8080/APP/process', How do I modify this as well

Comment: I should be able to hit my application first to check if that works

Comment: Just try it. An URL as in your first question should work. If it doesn't, please edit your question to include a concrete problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I hit my application from windows. Is it
>   http://x.y.z.k:8080//MYAPPNAME(war file name)/?

If 8080 is the port Tomcat is configured to listen on (I think by default, it is), then that is correct.  Bare in mind the web app name is case sensitive.  You can configure this setting in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml

> How do i check the java logs in the linux env?

Since you're using a remote shell over SSH, you will want to use either tail or less to monitor logs in real time.  The log files are stored in $TOMCAT_HOME/logs.

Try

```
$ less +F /path/to/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

catalina.out is the main file when running Tomcat on *nix systems.

> Also I have a set of files that I read from my windows folders as in
>   C://uploads//file.txt or C:\DeveloperTool\Pluggins\
>
> I replaced them with the linux structure in my java code. as
>   /home/opt/file.txt Will this work?

As Lutz Horn mentioned in the comments, try it.  In theory, that should work fine as long as the permissions are setup properly.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your reply.I have checked the port and it is 8080.Should I make any changes in tomcat-users.xml. I am unable to hit http://10.x.y.z:8080/MYAPP. I have checked the case too.It is the same. I have checked catalina.out too. It shows the logs until my the point where my app is deployed and server is up.But only if I am able to hit the application url ,will I be able to check points 2 and 3.Please advice

Comment: This could be a firewall issue, or Tomcat may not be listening all interfaces or perhaps the app is not deploying.  Knowing what type of error you get will help us narrow it down for you.